# Does weka filter keep the order of the instances

Tags: filter, weka

In weka, when applying filter on instances, like following

```
        // Filter the non-numeric attribute
        Instances data;
        Instances newData;

        Remove remove = new Remove();
        ......
        newData = Filter.useFilter(data, remove);
```

Will the order of instances in newData be exactly the same with the order of instances in data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'Remove' Filter wipes away an attribute instead of instances, but the order is still preserved.

As for the instance filters, they should also retain the order (unless specific filters reorder the dataset according to their documentation).

I tried this on the RemoveWithValues instance filter and the order was preserved after it was applied.